# How do I demonstrate the type of kernel compression in practice?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compression

I have to find out the **type of compression** of the linux kernel of my arch linux system, but I can't find a way to get it more than the theory: now `bzip2` (`bz`), formerly `gzip` (`z`).

In my computer I run the command:

```
$ file /boot/vmlinuz-linux
/boot/vmlinuz-linux: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 5.3.11-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 12 Nov 2019 22:19:48 +0000, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x5, Normal VGA
```

Looking at the theory, I see that `bzImage` must be compressed by `gzip (z)`, but I can't prove it:

> The bzImage was compressed using `gzip` until Linux 2.6.30 which introduced more algorithms. Although there is the popular misconception that the `bz` prefix means that bzip2 compression is used (the bzip2 package is often distributed with tools prefixed with `bz`, such as `bzless`, `bzcat`, etc.), this is not the case.

Is there any way to prove it on my own machine? or is the theory itself, in this case, "empirical"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To conclusively determine what compression was used for a given kernel image, without needing to run it or find its configuration, you can follow the approach used by the kernel’s own [`extract-vmlinux`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/extract-vmlinux) script:

- look for the compressor’s signature in the image:

  - `gunzip`: `\037\213\010`
  - `xz`: `\3757zXZ\000`
  - `bzip2`: `BZh`
  - `lzma`: `\135\0\0\0`
  - `lzo`: `\211\114\132`
  - `lz4`: `\002!L\030`
  - `zstd`: `(\265/\375`
- try to extract the data from the image, starting at the offset of any signature you’ve found;
- check that the result (if any) is an ELF image.

I’ve adapted the script [here](https://gist.github.com/skitt/288c0c52b51b5863947a5d6c1180c9f3) so that it only reports the compression type. I’m not including it here because it is licensed under the GPL 2 only.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! What is the problem that it is GPL 2 only? It should not restrict modification and sharing.

Comment: @Ashark [the license used for content on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) isn’t compatible with GPL 2. Since I’m not the sole copyright holder, I can’t republish the script under a different license.

Answer (score 7):

You can look at what compression methods your kernel supports.  Only one can be  selected, so that'll prove which one it is.

Here, I'm using gzip:

```
$ zgrep CONFIG_KERNEL_ /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP=y
# CONFIG_KERNEL_BZIP2 is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZMA is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_XZ is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZO is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZ4 is not set
```

Comment: In my case I have received an exit like this: 

`# CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_BZIP2 is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZMA is not set
CONFIG_KERNEL_XZ=y
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZO is not set
# CONFIG_KERNEL_LZ4 is not set
`

Comment: The only yes is `CONFIG_KERNEL_XZ`, is this normal?

Comment: The kernel compression mode is a Kconfig choice, so there’s only ever one which is enabled. `CONFIG_KERNEL_XZ` indicates that the kernel is compressed with `xz`; that’s fine.

Comment: If `XZ` is selected, then `XZ` is what you have.  What is "normal" is relative.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english, what I meant by "normal" was if it's common not to use the compression given in the theory

Comment: I think the misunderstanding here comes from “the theory” — if your theory is that `bzImage` should be compressed using `bzip2`, the quote you give explicitly states that that is *not* the case. The default is `gzip`, but any other compression mode supported by the kernel is valid. The reason there are different modes available is that each one is a compromise; see [their descriptions in the kernel source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/Kconfig#n198) for details.

Answer (score 0):

VMlinuz has been compressed in gzip as you can see in the following links:

http://www.linfo.org/vmlinuz.html

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mhhaque/entry/anatomy_of_the_initrd_and_vmlinuz?lang=en

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux

Ironically, the webpage says that a lot of people confuses the extension with bzip2 as you can see bellow:

> A compiled kernel named zImage file is created on some older systems and is retained on newer ones for backward compatibility. Both zImage and bzImage are compressed with **gzip**. The difference is that zImage decompresses into low memory (i.e., the first 640kB), and bzImage decompresses into high memory (more than 1MB). There is a common misconception that **bzImage** is compressed with the bzip2 utility; actually, the b just stands for big.

I hope that you will find the information helpful.

Comment: The Wikipedia page you link to explicitly mentions other compression formats; it’s not just `gzip` (although that *is* the default).